# Find and delete Duplicate in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From a User I am given a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array (
       [classCode] => Array ( 
                             [0] => class44 
                             [1] => class67
                             [2] => class34
                             [3] => class34
                             [4] => class44
                            ) 
       [className] => Array ( 
                             [0] => phy
                             [1] => mat 
                             [2] => chy
                             [3] => sci
                             [4] => phy
                            ) 
       )
```

I need to find duplicate values in the arrays and also should consider '[classCode]' as primary key and should return as shown below array.

```
Array (
       [classCode] => Array ( 
                             [0] => class44 
                             [1] => class67
                             [2] => class34
                            ) 
       [className] => Array ( 
                             [0] => phy
                             [1] => mat 
                             [2] => chy
                            ) 
       )
```

Comment: use array_unique()

Comment: i have not tried any one

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map`:

```
$result = array_map(function ($items) {
    return array_unique($items);
}, $your_array);
```